# How to find the inverse of a Jacobian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

The Jacobian matrix $\mathbf J$ is defined by
$$\mathbf J=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial \mu_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial \mu_k}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\dfrac{\partial y_k}{\partial \mu_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial y_k}{\partial \mu_k}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

How do I find $\mathbf J ^ {-1}$ if it exists? Is there a way to find it without differentiating each function?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to calculate the Jacobi matrix of coordinates change form $(y_i)$ to $(\mu_i)$ i.e. matrix of derivative $D(y(\mu))$.
Since coordinate change is invertible, you can first invert coordinates back, from $(\mu_i)$ to $(y_i)$, and then calculate a matrix $D(\mu(y))$.
If we denote $J = D(y(\mu))$ it follows that $J^{-1}= D(\mu(y))$, because
$$
D(y(\mu)) \circ D(\mu(y)) = D(E) = E
$$
where $E$ is identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much!